# How to find the average of distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: hive

Below is a piece of input data from 200000 lines.

[image: Input]

And I'm using the below command to find the average and expecting O/P like: M 50% F 50%

```
select avg(sum(case when col1='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col2='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col3='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col4='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col5='M' then 1 end)) as M,

   avg(sum(case when col1='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col2='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col3='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col4='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col5='F' then 1 end)) as F
       from household;
```

But shows an error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query in Hive. It would work just fine.

```
SELECT 
    y.M1/(y.M1 + y.F1) * 100 AS M,
    y.F1/(y.M1 + y.F1) * 100 AS F
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (x.SumMCol1 + x.SumMCol2 + x.SumMCol3 + x.SumMCol4 + x.SumMCol5) AS M1,
        (x.SumFCol1 + x.SumFCol2 + x.SumFCol3 + x.SumFCol4 + x.SumFCol5) AS F1
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            SUM(IF(col1 = 'M', 1, 0)) AS SumMCol1,
            SUM(IF(col2 = 'M', 1, 0)) AS SumMCol2,
            SUM(IF(col3 = 'M', 1, 0)) AS SumMCol3,
            SUM(IF(col4 = 'M', 1, 0)) AS SumMCol4,
            SUM(IF(col5 = 'M', 1, 0)) AS SumMCol5,
            SUM(IF(col1 = 'F', 1, 0)) AS SumFCol1,
            SUM(IF(col2 = 'F', 1, 0)) AS SumFCol2,
            SUM(IF(col3 = 'F', 1, 0)) AS SumFCol3,
            SUM(IF(col4 = 'F', 1, 0)) AS SumFCol4,
            SUM(IF(col5 = 'F', 1, 0)) AS SumFCol5,
            COUNT(*) AS TotalRows
        FROM 
            household
    ) x
) y;
```

Here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9cf85/2) to SQL Fiddle to try out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9cf85/2

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error.

**FAILED: ParseException line 14:4 cannot recognize input near 'FROM' '(' 'SELECT' in selection target**

BTW, I've edited the command as shown below, to pull the O/P from 8 columns. I hope it is valid.

`SELECT 
    y.H1/(y.H1 + y.P1 + y.U1 + y.W1 + y.Y1) * 100 AS H,
    y.P1/(y.H1 + y.P1 + y.U1 + y.W1 + y.Y1) * 100 AS P,
    y.U1/(y.H1 + y.P1 + y.U1 + y.W1 + y.Y1) * 100 AS U,
    y.W1/(y.H1 + y.P1 + y.U1 + y.W1 + y.Y1) * 100 AS W,
    y.Y1/(y.H1 + y.P1 + y.U1 + y.W1 + y.Y1) * 100 AS Y
FROM (`

Comment: The query is not complete. The above error could be result of misaligned braces. Could you write the query in SQL Fiddle and share the link? That way, I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Apologies, there's ',' in the end of the 15th line. Query executed successfully and showing the exact answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Cheers! :)